# Does the DocuSugn eSignature API support embedding maps in an HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html, docusignapi

According to the [DocuSign Docs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/responsive/setting-tabs/) on the html tags allowed, I don't see any script tag or iframe tag in the list of Supported HTML, attribute, and CSS elements. I want to embed a map in a document and send it in a DocuSign Envelope. Are there any special tags that DocuSign permits to support this kind of problem.

I need to know if there is a solution for this kind of problem or if there isn't any. Any suggestions will be highly valued.

Below is a list of tags that are allowed. I got it from the official DocuSign API developer Docs

```
div
span
p
strong
b
em
i
s
pre
u
h1
h2
h3
h4
h5
h6
ul
ol
li
dl
dt
dd
button
a
br
hr
table
thead
tbody
tfoot
caption
col
colgroup
tr
th
td
img
```

Comment: Isn’t the whole idea that the content within a DocuSign envelope is static? If you allowed scripts, you could change the content of the document retroactively and effectively have a “signature” from someone that appears completely differently after the fact. The only option you probably have is to generate a static image of the map in question and embed it with `<img>`.

Answer (score 0):

Our Responsive Signing / SmartSection functionalities allow you to embed some web elements into an envelope -- however many elements that were deemed a potential security concern were disallowed, iFrames and Scripts are two of these elements. DocuSign in general does not support iFrames beyond just the basic Error -- using them tends to cause conflicts between our system and the customer browser (X-Frame issues) so they are highly discouraged.

Unfortunately we do not presently support either of these functionalities.

Sorry I don't have a better answer for you.

Regards,

Matt

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate

Comment: How can I put an <a> tag href attribute in an html document for docusign. I have tried toput it there manually but it doesn't work when I click it via the envelope in my email